# How does the following web2py code provide database record creation?

Tags: web2py

In the [web2py book chapter on Forms and Validators](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators) the author states that the following code:

```
def manage():
    table=db[request.args(0)]
    form = crud.update(table,request.args(1))
    table.id.represent = lambda id, row: A('edit:',id,_href=URL(args=(request.args(0),id)))
    search, rows = crud.search(table)
    return dict(form=form,search=search,rows=rows)
```

lets you search, **create** and edit any records from any table where the tablename is passed request.args(0)

However I see no way that this code can create records. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line:

```
form = crud.update(table,request.args(1))
```

when the URL does not include an arg after the table name, `request.args(1)` will return `None`, and `crud.update(table, None)` is equivalent to `crud.create(table)` (in fact, internally the latter simply calls the former).

So, a URL like `/myapp/mycontroller/manage/mytable/5` will provide an update form for record 5, but `/myapp/mycontroller/manage/mytable` will provide a create form.

Also, note that `Crud` has been deprecated. Prefer `SQLFORM` and `SQLFORM.grid`.

Comment: `Crud` has been deprecated? [The web2py book says it's a new feature](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#CRUD) --- has experimenting with it shown it to be less useful than its predecessors?

Comment: Not a new feature -- the book was simply never updated after the word "recent" was used to describe Crud several years ago (there were no predecessors). There was supposed to be a [book update](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py-developers/xiFE7DPRYl8/wibME1BNFQAJ) indicating the deprecation (doesn't look like it's happened yet). Most of the Crud functionality is now covered by `SQLFORM.process` and `SQLFORM.grid`.